# Book on the geometry of rotationally symmetric riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

I would like to find some references where there are specific computations and properties of rotationally symmetric riemannian manifolds, e.g. spectrum of the laplacian, schrödinger operators, examples of geometric flows, minimal manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, stability, computations for spheres, catenoids, etc.

Edit: Some basic examples I know are from Grigor'yan's "Analytic and geometric background of recurrence and non-explosion of the Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds", section 3 and others examples treating radial solutions. It would be very useful for self study to find something more exhaustive or comprehensive in the direction of geometry for these families of examples.

Edit 2: As clarification, I am thinking on Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ such that in local polar/radial coordinates the metric has the form $g = dr^2 + a^2(r) d\theta^2$, cf. Grigor'yan, section 3, and surely others references (that I am precisely asking for). The other tensors and local formulas should normally depend only on the radial coordinate $r$ and the expression of $a$, and the study of many geometric PDEs simplify to ODEs. Thus some explicit computations become feasible and one can gain intuition studying the formulas obtained, e.g. to the case geodesic spheres (constant $r$), taking limits on $r$, etc.

Comment: You should define what you mean by a rotationally symmetric Riemannian metric. Do you mean that locally the metric has this form? Or some global condition (I cannot think of any)?

Comment: Yes, the local expression of the metric as warped product $g = dr^2 + a(r) d\theta^2$. My aim is to work out some examples such as the Bryant soliton, cf. https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/3DRotSymRicciSolitons.pdf, but since my experience with riemannian geometry comes from do Carmo's style, I am having struggle with the new methods. Other examples, there is a paper of Tam and Zhou in 2009 computing the index of stability of the catenoid; "radial cases", "model cases", as motivating examples in many papers to gain intuition, but where to learn the fundamentals? (without an advisor).

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify it. In the current form, it seems that your class of metrics is the same as the one of metrics of (locally) constant sectional curvature.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. I will clarify the question. The sectional curvature of $g = dr^2 + a^2(r) d\theta^2$ is computed using the expression of $a$, cf. Grigor'yan's review paper mentioned in the first Edit, section 15.2. The locally constant sectional curvature cases correspond to $a(r)=r$ for $K \equiv 0$, $a(r)=\sin(r)$ for $K \equiv 1$ and $a(r)=\sinh(r)$ for $K \equiv -1$.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you require local rotational symmetry at every point, which will imply constant curvature. But, an edit would clarify your definition.

Comment: Still unclear. What do you mean by "in local polar/radial coordinates"? Do you mean for every point in $M$ as the center of your radial coordinates the metric has this form? Or do you mean that there is a covering of $M$ such that the metric in each chart satisfies this equation?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No covering here, as a starting point. I see them locally as a trivial fibration of geodesic spheres over an interval (with coordinate $r$), each fiber having the round metric conformally multiplied by the function $a$.